# Match value from text using java regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to match this value "wJJNfeRPLC" using java regex from this text:

*"et le mot de passe suivants :

nom d'utilisateur : Information

mot de passe : **wJJNfeRPLC**

Vous pouvez aussi vous connecter en cliquant sur ce lien ou le copier-coller
dans votre navigateur"*

I tried this but I m not expert on regex

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(^mot de passe(.*));
```

Following Cyrille Karmann answer

```
    String text = (String)message[1].getContent();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=mot de passe : )(\\w+)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
```

Thanks

Comment: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(^mot de passe : (.*));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. What you want is a string who is preceded by the string "mot de passe : ", and end with the end of line.

Therefore the regexp should be like this:

```
(?<=mot de passe : )(\w+)$
```

It uses a *positive lookbehind* (the part with the funny `?<=` at the beginning) to check that the part you capture (the password) is preceded by "mot de passe : ".

It is used like this:

```
String string = "et le mot de passe suivants :\n\n" +
                "nom d'utilisateur : Information\n\n" +
                "mot de passe : wJJNfeRPLC\n\n" +
                "Vous pouvez aussi vous connecter en cliquant sur ce lien ou le copier-coller dans votre navigateur";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=mot de passe : )(\\w+)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if (matcher.find()) {
  String password = matcher.group();
  System.out.println(password);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for but I don't understand why I can not matching this word. String text = (String)message[1].getContent();
              System.out.println(text);
              
              Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=mot de passe : )(\\w+)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
              Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

Comment: You used "\n\n" but in my case it's "\r\n". It is managed by Pattern.MULTILINE?

Comment: yes it is, but maybe you have some other whitespace characters after that. Maybe it is better to use a word boundary (\b) than the end of line. Can you try `"(?<=mot de passe : )(\\w+)\\b"` ?

Comment: still nothing, here the string content:       nom d\'utilisateur : Information\r\nmot de passe : wJJNfeRPLC\r\n\r\nVous pouvez aussi vous connecter

Comment: It work fine, thanks very much, i've tried this: Information\r\nmot de passe : )(\\w+)\\b